# what is the best way to have daily scheduled reports on my website / database

Tags: asp.net, email, cron, web-hosting

i have a website that is being hosted on www.webhost4life.com.  Its a basic asp.net mvc site with a backend of SQL Server.   I want to have a "script" or something that run a database query and sends out an email daily.  what is the best way to set this up using a hosted web provider to run every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows' task scheduler can do most things that cron can do.

Reached at Settings -> Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks

There are other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850556/how-to-emulate-cron-jobs-on-a-windows-server).