# Creating a content management system for dedicated use

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system

I've been trying to create a specialised CMS, as none of the current open-source ones fit my needs for this project.

I did my research on Google, tried multiple times but haven't got very far with this project.

I'm trying to create a CMS for a TV/episode guide which is [similar to this](http://library.digiguide.com/lib/programmenextshowing/Police%2C+Camera%2C+Action!-12578)
where records expire and delete from the database after expiration.

This is the design I'm trying to emulate:

[the programme](http://library.digiguide.com/lib/programme/24-84241/Drama/)

[a typical episode, could use .htaccess to remove php from name](http://library.digiguide.com/lib/episode/Under+Surveillance-714873)

[paginated episode display (using script that I found in search here possibly)](http://library.digiguide.com/lib/programmenextshowing/24-84241)

I don't have access to cron job as it's on Windows/Apache, so that's out the question for this one.

I'm not sure how to go about this successfully, anyone got any advice?

(Note:Although the linked site runs in ASP.NET, it's the design and feel of it I'm trying to emulate, except in PHP. I've managed to emulate that site's design, but with my own tweaks to it.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This question has entirely too much scope. What skill level are you at in coding/web design?

Comment: I don't understand at all what `cron` has to do with anything here. Shouldn't you first and foremost be concerned with much deeper, fundamental architectural questions?

Comment: I am competent at the basics of PHP; but actually creating any usable application is something I need to learn.

CSS I have some skill in, web design I am OK at.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you are asking but...

Windows has its own scheduler options similar to a cron (at), or you can run something like Quartz for scheduling inside Java containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to do scheduled tasks to delete expired records you should read:

[How to emulate cron jobs on a Windows Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850556/how-to-emulate-cron-jobs-on-a-windows-server)

Last resort you can take a page out from PHP sessions and run a script to do it when people visit the site (not every time, just randomly).