# Need to send SMS alert 15 minutes before start of appointment

Tags: php, scheduling

I have an application in PHP that helps people fix appointments.

How could I code to send SMS's 15 minutes before the start of the meeting time?

I have code that takes care of sending SMS's. I just need to call the send method at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is making a script that sends an SMS to everyone who has a meeting in 15 minutes and set a cron job (or something similar if not on Unix) to run the script every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: I'm using GoDaddy hosting with Windows. How do I run a cron job to do the tasks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850556/how-to-emulate-cron-jobs-on-a-windows-server suggests GoDaddy doesn't offer scheduling on their Windows servers but that thread lists some options.