# What is the simplest way to run some command once every 5 min in Window OS / VS?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

In the Linux world, the simplest way is to use a Cron job.  There is no Cron in Windows.  There is however Services, but that seem to be a lot of work.  What is the simplest way so a set of commands will run every 5 min or so?

To be more specific, the commands I need to run consist of moving some files, and updating a database.  Possibly written in C# so it's slightly more complicated than just a BAT script.

Comment: Windows has a Task Scheduler, and an `at` command.

Comment: It can run scripts and programs, so yes.

Comment: I second Task Scheduler. Very handy to save you from the trouble of developing services. I recommend to write a C# console application.

Comment: Maybe check into Quartz.net too? It's a .NET based job scheduler - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Task Scheduler is probably the best way to go, though an alternative is http://cronw.sourceforge.net/
It runs as a system service and only requires perl.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll accept this answer in 10min after it becomes available.

Comment: Task Scheduler is certainly the best way to handle this natively in Windows (though there are, of course, alternatives). You can do a large array of stuff including having a service run at set intervals as well making the service run at Windows start-up (before a user logs in).

Answer (score 0):

You can ofcourse run C# executables from  batch files or even directly from Task Scheduler. Open Task Scheduler and enter the path of your executable and configure it to run every 5 minutes. Make sure that appropriate version of .NET framework is installed.

Answer (score 0):

- Quartz.NET – This is a very complete cron job library. By far it has
  the most features.
- NCrontab – This is a simpler library that    implements a cron
  scheduler (no cron job).

For details see a link.
http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/
 and this question of SO also help You.
[What is equivelant of CRON jobs in ASP.NET - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226986/what-is-equivelant-of-cron-jobs-in-asp-net)