# Send email WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a webAPI project with reminder class

There it is

```
public class ReminderItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public DateTime RemindDate { get; set; }

    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorEmail { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }

}
```

I need to make add/update/delete events for it. This is all done already and works. But also I need to make email message sending to AuthorEmail on DateTime.  This is 
`RemindDate` property. But I never do this. Maybe you can help me, how I can do this? Or where I can read about this? Because I understood how to do this on program launch. Like, check DateTime now with DateTime in DB. But, how I can do this to make it automatically when the program is already running?

Comment: Maybe this will help --> [Task Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226986/what-is-the-equivalent-to-cron-jobs-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: You can use quartz.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a scheduled task run in the background and check if you need to send some emails. See here for a description in dotnetcore:
https://thinkrethink.net/2018/08/02/hostbuilder-ihost-ihostedserice-console-application/

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you have some deferred work! I'd recommend utilizing a email sending service like [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-api/). they have a schedule email api where you can send the details in, and they will wait until the date and time is met before sending (https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/scheduling_parameters.html)

If you are wanting your own solution using SMTP, it'll be more involved, since you will need to use a storage mechanism like azure service bus queue's and a web job to host the work that is scheduled.