# How can background tasks be executed from a library in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my job we are building Web Apps that rely on a common Enterprise class. This class has a method that sends a request to our server every time the app_start or app_end event triggers so we can monitor the status remotely. But we are now requiring that at least once a day the web app reports its status, a bit like telemetry. I don't know how to accomplish this, so far I have found some options, but some have limitations:

1. Use hangfire. I don't like this since it requires to setup a Database or add more tables and install a new Nuget package on each project, but could be my last option.
2. Use a Windows Service that reads databases. This could be less work but it can't access the Web App web.config code
3. Use a Javascript tasks that sends an AJAX request. This requires to have an open web browser and is a big risk.

I'm looking for a server side approach that could allow to set to trigger an event or function at 1am.

Comment: Is your application hosted on IIS? if yes, which version?

Comment: We used the IIS service auto start feature and during the app startup, we used a timer to do some cleanup at regular intervals. I guess the same thing can also be used in this case.

Comment: @Thangadurai yes, we are using IIS 10

Answer (score 0):

I would got with Hangifire.

It is dead easy to setup and very reliable.
You don't need to setup the database, you might want to check memory storage:

https://github.com/perrich/Hangfire.MemoryStorage

Also check:

[What is the equivalent to CRON jobs in ASP.NET? - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226986/what-is-the-equivalent-to-cron-jobs-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) instead of Hangfire (it is more lightweight).

Instead of a Javascript task that sends an AJAX request you can use a [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) or an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).