# Automatic accounts check every 24 hours for membership expiration

Tags: php

I'm having a user control panel (UCP) for my game server.
I offer different memberships (gold/silver/bronze etc) for money.
However, I want to run a PHP script every 24 hours, to run a check over the "users" database and see if 30 days have elapsed. I know how to create the function but I don't know how to make it work automatically. My host is using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Use the Task Scheduler to schedule the script running.

[Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850556/how-to-emulate-cron-jobs-on-a-windows-server)

Comment: I've heard about the Task Scheduler. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

### Linux / Unix / OS X

Scheduled jobs are call [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs under linux.

Configuring cronjobs usually requires you to use the [shell](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php) (over SSH). Sometimes a hosting provider might provide to schedule jobs through their control panel.

Here's are great article about [how to add a cronjob](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

### Windows

Under windows, you can use the task schedular to execute a job periodically. Read [this howto](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard) for that.

Comment: This is always my preferred approach. It works well because you can specify down to the minute granularity in running the script. Just make sure you have similar granularity in the membership expiration times.